# Strip everything except for the complete anchor tag - Perl

Tags: regex, bash, perl, curl, grep

I am needing to parse an HTML file and remove everything except for the anchor tags in their entirety. So for example:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>boom</p>
        <a href="/blah" rel="no-follow">Example</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I only need to keep:

```
<a href="/blah" rel="no-follow">Example</a>
```

I am using cURL to retrieve the html and a small snippet of code I found that strips everything but the anchor text of the tag. This is what I am using:

```
curl http://www.google.com 2>&1 | perl -pe 's/\<.*?\>//g'
```

Is there a simple command line way to do this? My end goal is to put this into a bash script and execute it. I am having a very difficult time understanding regular expressions and perl.

Comment: not quite sure why this would get a downvote

Comment: I suspect the DV is because parsing HTML with Regular Expressions is misguided, and instead one should use an actual HTML Parser.  Don't worry about it though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [`Mojolicious`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious) command line tool [`mojo`](https://metacpan.org/pod/mojo):

```
mojo get http://www.google.com 'a'
```

Outputs:

```
<a class="gb1" href="http://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&amp;tab=wi">Images</a>
<a class="gb1" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&amp;tab=wl">Maps</a>
<a class="gb1" href="https://play.google.com/?hl=en&amp;tab=w8">Play</a>
<a class="gb1" href="http://www.youtube.com/?tab=w1">YouTube</a>
<a class="gb1" href="http://news.google.com/nwshp?hl=en&amp;tab=wn">News</a>
<a class="gb1" href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm">Gmail</a>
<a class="gb1" href="https://drive.google.com/?tab=wo">Drive</a>
<a class="gb1" href="http://www.google.com/intl/en/options/" style="text-decoration:none"><u>More</u> »</a>
<a class="gb4" href="http://www.google.com/history/optout?hl=en">Web History</a>
<a class="gb4" href="/preferences?hl=en">Settings</a>
<a class="gb4" href="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&amp;continue=http://www.google.com/" id="gb_70" target="_top">Sign in</a>
<a href="/chrome/index.html?hl=en&amp;brand=CHNG&amp;utm_source=en-hpp&amp;utm_medium=hpp&amp;utm_campaign=en" onclick="google.promos&amp;&amp;google.promos.toast&amp;&amp; google.promos.toast.cl()">Install Google Chrome</a>
<a href="/advanced_search?hl=en&amp;authuser=0">Advanced search</a>
<a href="/language_tools?hl=en&amp;authuser=0">Language tools</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com/chrome/devices/index.html" onclick="google.promos&amp;&amp;google.promos.link&amp;&amp; google.promos.link.cl()">Chromebook: For students</a>
<a href="/intl/en/ads/">Advertising Programs</a>
<a href="/services/">Business Solutions</a>
<a href="https://plus.google.com/116899029375914044550" rel="publisher">+Google</a>
<a href="/intl/en/about.html">About Google</a>
<a href="/intl/en/policies/">Privacy &amp; Terms</a>
```

For a helpful 8 minute introductory video, check out: [Mojocast Episode 5](http://mojocasts.com/e5)

Answer (score 2):

Using Mojolicious, as @Miller above, but more exactly select the `<a ... rel=` :

If you have an html file

```
perl -Mojo -E 'say $_ for x(b("my.html")->slurp)->find("a[rel]")->each'
```

or for the online resource

```
perl -Mojo -E 'say $_ for g("http://example.com")->dom->find("a[rel]")->each'
#or
perl -Mojo -E 'g("http://example.com")->dom->find("a[rel]")->each(sub{say $_})'
```

Comment: The `mojo` command line tool also enables one to use more detailed searches.  The following pulls all the google ssl hrefs that are in a link with a class: `mojo get http://www.google.com 'a[class][href^=https]' attr href`

Answer (score 1):

If you want more granular control over your HTML, then you can use [HTML::TagParser](http://search.cpan.org/~kawasaki/HTML-TagParser-0.20/lib/HTML/TagParser.pm) module available on CPAN.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TagParser;

my $html = HTML::TagParser->new( '<html>
    <body>
        <p>boom</p>
        <a href="/blah" rel="no-follow">Example</a>
    </body>
</html>' );

my @list = $html->getElementsByTagName( "a" );

for my $elem ( @list ) {
    my $name = $elem->tagName;
    my $attr = $elem->attributes;
    my $text = $elem->innerText;
    print "<$name";
    for my $key ( sort keys %$attr ) {
        print " $key=\"$attr->{$key}\"";
    }
    print $text eq "" ? " />" : ">$text</$name>" , "\n";
}
```

#### Output:

```
<a href="/blah" rel="no-follow">Example</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ingy döt Net's [pQuery](https://metacpan.org/release/pQuery) deserves a mention:

```
perl -MpQuery -E 'pQuery("http://www.ubu.com/sound/barthes.html")
 ->find("a")->each(sub{say pQuery($_)->toHtml})'
```

Just the links:

```
perl -MpQuery -E 'pQuery("http://www.ubu.com/sound/barthes.html")
  ->find("a")->each(sub{say $_->{href}})'
```

Although - unlike `mojo` - there's no command line tool (*i.e.* not **yet** - it's not that kind of tool *per se* and is still "under construction"), it's a module to have on your watch list.